# Remove exact matching word using sed

Tags: sed

I want to remove word  'foggy' from the string. It fails. Why?

```
echo 'foggy light' | sed 's/\<foggy\>//g'
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What's the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: @userunknown of course: [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), installed by default on **all** versions of Ubuntu, has `\<` and `\>` for matching start-of-word and end-of-word. I suspect this is yet another Android question. OP has been know to post a number of questions about some Android app that provides Unix commands, while pretending it is Ubuntu OP is using.

Comment: For removing the word foggy in above scenario, you don't need start-of-word/end-of-word-markers.

Comment: sed version 4.0

Comment: Which it is not on any current version of Ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sed, so yet again an off-topic question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the above string, you don't need start-of-word/end-of-word markers and you may use:

```
echo 'foggy light' | sed 's/foggy//g'
```

For the additional question in the comment:

Indeeed, my sed version

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

supports the Syntax with `\<...\>`

```
echo 'foggy foggylight' | sed 's/\<foggy\>//g'
foggylight
```

If it doesn't work for you, report your sed version and read its manpage. For my sed, this syntax works too:

```
echo 'foggy foggylight' | sed 's/\bfoggy\b//g'
foggylight
```

`\b` can be memorized as ***boundary***.

Comment: It's not `<` and `>` but `\<` and`\>`.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions

Comment: Ok. And how to drop just the word foggy alone, not touching foggylight?   echo 'foggy foggylight' | sed 's/foggy//g'

Comment: @JosefKlimuk: Added extension